# Access c_char_p_Array_256 in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a native python bridge to some C code, which returns a pointer to an array (array of structs). The struct contains some character arrays (strings). But how can I get from a `c_char_p_Array_NNN` to an actual Python string?

```
typedef struct td_Group
{
    unsigned int group_id;
    char groupname[256];
    char date_created[32];
    char date_modified[32];
    unsigned int user_modified;
    unsigned int user_created;
} Group;

int getGroups(LIBmanager *, Group **);

############# python code below: 
class Group(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("group_id", c_uint),
                ("groupname", c_char_p*256),
                ("date_created", c_char_p*32),
                ("date_modified", c_char_p*32),
                ("user_modified", c_uint),
                ("user_created", c_uint)]


def somefunc():
    myGroups = c_void_p()
    count = libnativetest.getGroups( nativePointer, byref(myGroups) )
    print "got " + str(count) + " groups!!"
    myCastedGroups = cast( myGroups, POINTER(Group*count) )
    for x in range(0,count):
        theGroup = cast( myCastedGroups[x], POINTER(Group) )
        theGroupName = theGroup.contents.groupname 
        ### Now how do I access theGroupName as a python string?
        # it is a c_char_p_Array_256 presently
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type should be `c_char*256`, not `c_char_p*256`, because it's a `char[256]`, not a `char *[256]`.

`string_at(theGroupName, sizeof(theGroupName))`