# Access array of c-structs using Python ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I have a C-function that allocates memory at the address passed to and is accessed via Python. The pointer contents does contain an array of structs in the C code, but I am unable to get ctypes to access the array properly beyond the 0th element. How can I get the proper memory offset to be able to access the non-zero elements? Python's ctypes.memset is complaining about TypeErrors if I try to use their ctypes.memset function.

```
typedef struct td_Group
{
    unsigned int group_id;
    char groupname[256];
    char date_created[32];
    char date_modified[32];
    unsigned int user_modified;
    unsigned int user_created;
} Group;

int getGroups(LIBmanager * handler, Group ** unallocatedPointer);

############# python code below: 
class Group(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("group_id", c_uint),
                ("groupname", c_char*256),
                ("date_created", c_char*32),
                ("date_modified", c_char*32),
                ("user_modified", c_uint),
                ("user_created", c_uint)]


myGroups = c_void_p()
count = libnativetest.getGroups( nativePointer, byref(myGroups) )
casted = cast( myGroups, POINTER(Group*count) )
for x in range(0,count):
    theGroup = cast( casted[x], POINTER(Group) )
    # this only works for the first entry in the array:
    print "~~~~~~~~~~" + theGroup.contents.groupname
```

Related: [Access c_char_p_Array_256 in Python using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314275/access-c-char-p-array-256-in-python-using-ctypes)

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add the entire traceback.

Comment: @yak: When one is playing around with ctypes, tracebacks are a privilege not always available. If you step out of the line, the norm is the Python interpreter ending up in a segfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a new type which is an array of Group:

```
GroupArray = Group * count
```

Then create an instance of a GroupArray this way:

```
group_array = GroupArray.from_address(myGroups.value)
```

Then your loop would work like this:

```
for x in range(0,count):
    print "~~~~~~~~~~" + group_array[x].groupname
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is printing garbage characters. Note that `myGroups` is a pointer to the first element of the array (a `Group*`), not a `Group**`. The call to `libnativetest.getGroups` is passing the address of `myGroups`, which is making it a `Group**`.

Comment: Oops, you are correct. That's a bug - try the fix I put in. Use myGroups.value instead of addressof(myGroups).

Answer (score 4):

D Hess put me in the right direction; The solution was:

```
GroupArray = POINTER(Group * count)
group_array = GroupArray.from_address(addressof(myGroups))
for x in range(0,count):
    print "~~~~~~~~~~" + group_array.contents[x].groupname
```